# Dependency resolution in Maven/Jenkins sometimes fails, using a private nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus

In my company we have a very strict server network which can only access the internet partly. So, we have a Jenkins master which can access the Maven central repo through a proxy. There are also 2 Jenkins slaves which cannot access the network, but the master.

On the master are the Jenkins master, a SonarQube server and the Nexus repository. Most of the time, the builds run without any issues. But sometimes the resolution fails for no obvious reasons.
The develop branch is build hourly, so even if nothing changes at all, it sometimes fails.

> [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.5 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:jar:3.0.5:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:pom:3.0.5 from/to
>   project-group
>   (http://private-nexus-repo/repository/project-group/):
>   /home/jenkins/slave/workspace/develop-LYKF76YCB7AFY5V4CVFSHITCBJ3WQYJGX3P2EZA6RWBRV5K2KN4Q/.repository/org/codehaus/mojo/findbugs-maven-plugin/3.0.5/findbugs-maven-plugin-3.0.5.pom.part
>   (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden) -> [Help 1]

When I check the repository manually the dependencies are there. I can only think of network issues...
Do you have any suggestions what the issue could be?

Comment: I do not completely understand your architecture: Does your Jenkins master access MavenCentral directly, or do you proxy MavenCentral in your company Nexus repository?

Comment: It uses a proxy to access it. We got a http/https proxy from the IT department.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your answer. So do you proxy MavenCentral in Nexus, or does Jenkins access it through that special proxy (without the company Nexus)?

Comment: Nexus has set up the http proxy and has a proxy repository to the Maven Central. The server itself has no internet access, only through the http proxy. We have a "proxy" to Maven Central, a "local" repository which holds our snapshots and a "group" which combine both. The maven build uses the group.

Comment: Your Jenkins slaves have access to your private Nexus? What is the difference between your Jenkins slaves and the Jenkins master except for residing on different machines?

Comment: Yes, the slaves can access the private Nexus. Jenkins master server (which runs the Nexus as well) and the slaves can access the Maven central repository through the http proxy. Both machines have a very strict access to other machines and especially internet access. Both machines are in different networks.

Comment: Then you probably really have a sporadically failing network...

Comment: Thanks. I think that is the issue too. I really have no ideas anymore what the issue could be otherwise.

Comment: Nexus has a request log. Maybe you should have a look there.